# Cast Entry to appropriate type to access fields and functions in module

Tags: craft3

Newbie to Craft CMS. I am trying to send a push notification to an app when an entry of specific type (NewsItem) is saved, and I'm doing so via a Craft Module. I got this code snippet from another StackExchange question, and I have changed it a bit to implement it according to my needs:

```
        Craft::$app->elements->on(Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT, function(ElementEvent $event) {

            // Make sure it's an entry.
            if ($event->element instanceof craft\elements\Entry) {
                $entry = $event->element;

                // Check if it's in the section you care about
                if ($entry->sectionId == 1) {
                    // Do your custom logic

                        if(isset($entry->photo))
                            $image_name = $entry->photo->getUrl();
                        else
                            $image_name = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $entry->youtubeVideoCode . '/0.jpg';
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\AssetQuery::getUrl()
```

I may be wrong, but I'm assuming I have to cast $entry to (NewsItem) somewhere in the code to access the getUrl() function? How and where do I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer is mostly unrelated to your question, but I wanted to provide some context, first!

Entry Types don't get their own PHP classes. All Entries are just instances of the `craft\elements\Entry` class, distinguished by their `section` (`$entry->getSection()`) and `type` (`$entry->getType()`) values.

If you need to check the section *and* type of your entry, you can compare against the `sectionId` and `typeId` properties. Keep in mind that these IDs may be different, across environments, so it's better to use the `handle` and keep it in sync with your `project.yml`:

```php
if ($entry->getSection()->handle == 'mySectionHandle' && $entry->getType()->handle == 'myEntryTypeHandle') {
  // Your logic!
}
```

Ok, now on to the error you're seeing!

```
Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\AssetQuery::getUrl()
```

This is actually telling you that the accessed field/property (`photo`) returns an object that doesn't have a `getUrl()` method.

Unless [relational field data](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html) is [eager-loaded](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html), accessing its property will return an `ElementQuery` (in your case, an `AssetQuery`), prepped to return the related Elements.

So, before accessing methods on the expected value (an `Asset` Element), you have to execute the query:

```php
$photo = $entry->photo->one();

if ($photo) {
  // At least one photo was attached! You can safely access the Asset object's properties + methods:
  $url = $photo->getUrl();
} else {
  // Set a default:
  $url = 'https://...';
}
```

Comment: Understood well & working perfectly. Thanks v.much for providing the detailed context. Marking your answer as the correct one. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again. I'm facing a new issue with Craft. Since you are knowledgeable about Craft, maybe you could help me out with this one too? Thanks in advance. https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/elementsevent-after-save-element-event-handler-in-module-being-called-mult